# Is there enough matter orbiting the sun to make a second sun?

Tags: the-sun, solar-system, accretion

I read somewhere a long time ago that there is enough matter in our solar system in the form of rocks and dust to create another sun.Is this correct? Was our solar system trying to create a 2 star system?

Comment: If you have an advanced civilization able to "make a sun", you can do starlifting to extract material from the original Sun for that purpose. As it becomes smaller, it will become less bright, and longer-living. (Though then the question is better for worldbuilding.SE.)

Comment: What does "orbiting the sun" mean to you? Is that out to the orbit of Pluto, or only of Neptune?

Either way, what do you see as the mass of the sun, and of the rest of the system?

Comment: Although the solar system doesn't _currently_ have enough extra mass to form an additional star, star formation is a complex process which typically generates multiple stars together ( http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/ast122/lectures/lec13.html ) and some of the initial matter can be slung out of the individual star systems, although it's unlikely that our particular solar system ever had enough for two stars: https://phys.org/news/2015-10-minimum-mass-proto-solar-disk.html

Comment: Can you say where "Was our solar system trying to create a 2 star system?" comes from? That doesn't seem related to the OQ.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, "orbiting the Sun" generally means something that is gravitationally bound, rather than referring to a specific distance.

Comment: @Mark Thanks and while that is wholly logical, I feel a need to ask how it is helpful here? Don't you accept that gravitational bounds decrease with distance?

Answer (score 60):

The vast majority of the stuff in the solar system other than the Sun itself  is contained in one body, Jupiter. The total mass of the solar system is estimated to be about 1.0014 solar masses, or about one solar mass plus 1.4 Jupiter masses. (Jupiter's mass is a bit less than 0.001 solar masses.) Using the highest estimates on the mass of the Oort cloud, the total mass of the solar system, excluding the Sun itself, is about 30 Jupiter masses. These early estimates have been shown to be wrong. Current estimates are that the mass of the Oort cloud is one or two Earth masses. Even if the hypothesized planet IX does exist and is as large as some hypothesize (about five Earth masses), that will only budge the estimated 1.0014 solar masses by a tiny, tiny bit.

The smallest possible star, defined as something capable of fusing hydrogen, is about 65 to 80 Jupiter masses. The answer is no.

Comment: And a good part of that matter wouldn't be useful for forming a star as it's not useful as fusion fuel (in fact would poison the fusion process). Which is one reason stars die, their fusion process gets poisoned by heavy isotopes.

Comment: @Panzercrisis https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B%5C%2840%29jupiter+mass%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%29sun+mass%5C%2841%29%5D

Comment: @Panzercrisis The mass of the smallest possible star is typically stated in terms of Jupiter's mass rather than the Sun's mass. There are many good reasons for this.

Comment: @Panzercrisis 0.001% --> 0.00001, I think the % sign is an error there, or it should be 0.1%.

Comment: @NickT Okay, yeah, that must've been a typo.

Comment: "Using the highest estimates on the mass of the Oort cloud, the total mass of the solar system, excluding the Sun itself, is about 30 Jupiter masses." That phrasing is confusing. It fails to clearly distinguish between reality and beliefs about reality. Clearer would be "Previously, the highest estimates of the mass of the Oort cloud resulted in the total mass of the solar system, excluding the Sun itself, to be calculated as 30 Jupiter masses."

Answer (score 28):

No.  The total mass of the planets, asteroids, dust etc in the solar system is only about 0.1% of the mass of the sun.  There is not nearly enough to make even a small star.

Comment: 0.1 % is about 330 Earth masses  .

Comment: @DaveTheWave That's not nearly enough. A better number is 0.0014 Sun masses, or about 1.4 Jupiter masses. The smallest possible star is 65 to 80 Jupiter masses, depending on who one reads.

Comment: There's probably *at least* another 0.1% in the "vacuum", by which I mean the 3 to 10 atoms per cubic centimeter in the empty regions of space.  By my calculations, 1 cubic light year would contain about 1,000 Earth masses (assuming those were all protons) per atom per cubic centimeter.

Comment: I'm not sure that counts as "rocks and dust". On the other hand, I'm not sure if planets count as "rocks and dust".  However, no matter which way you cut it, there isn't enough "stuff" for a second star.

Comment: @Michael 1000 Earth masses is a bit more than 3 Jupiter masses, so not enough stuff to cut it. Moreover, the Sun and the planets are very good at either expelling small material from the solar system or making such material drop into the Sun. (The zodiacal light falls into the latter category.) Even if what you wrote is true (which it isn't), an additional three Jupiter masses will not cut it.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes, I'm aware that 1000 Earth masses isn't enough to cut it... it would need to be 1000 times larger still to equal the mass of the sun.  But why do you say that what I wrote isn't true?  Are my calculations off on the total mass present in the "empty" space of the solar system?

Comment: @Michael I suspect your number is too large by a factor of $10^8$. The vast majority of protons in interplanetary space come from the Sun (aka the solar wind, which arises from things such as sunspots and coronal mass ejections). The density of those solar emissions drops with the square of distance from the Sun. Moreover, it is not spherically symmetrical. The majority of those particles are near the plane of the Sun's equator. (continued)

Comment: Assuming spherical symmetry and a density of 13 protons / cubic cm at 1 AU I get $10^{-5}$ earth masses for a sphere with a radius of one light year. That is certainly overkill due to the assumption of spherical symmetry and is smaller than your calculation by a factor of $10^{-8}$.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks! That makes sense.  In the back of my head I was setting 1 proton / cm^3 as a lower bound, forgetting that intergalactic space is 1 proton / m^3, not cm^3!